# JavaScript redirect issue in some versions of IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, redirect

I've got the following js (in a .net web page) that is triggered when the site visitor selects an option from a dropdown list / select. The result is that a link is opened eg. a pdf, using the value attribute of the dropdownlist / select for the url.

```
$(function () {
    // bind change event to select

    // bind change event to select
    $('#mjdownload').on('change', function () {
        var url = $(this).val(); // get selected value
        if (url) { // require a URL
            window.location = url; // redirect
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

This works fine in firefox and chrome and win 8 with latest version of IE. **However**, **IE 8 on win 7** doesn't result in anything happening (eg it doesn't open the pdf).

Comment: Have you tried appending ".href"?  Like so "window.location.href = url". Had same problem in the past, IE is weird about such things sometimes :S

Comment: @Jose, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Can you post the actual 'url' string that displays correctly when the window loads in the other browsers?

Comment: Make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) please.

Comment: Are you sure that the change event is firing in IE and `url` has a value in IE8/Win7?

Comment: @Jose If you want to make an answer I will mark yours as correct. Thanks.

Comment: @PhillHealey Only if it worked for you my friend :)  Did you get it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried appending ".href"? Like so `window.location.href = url` Had same problem in the past, IE is weird about such things sometimes :S

Answer (score 0):

I think this is sort of what you are trying to do?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("a").on("click", function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
    var pdf = $(this).attr("href");
    alert(pdf);
        if (pdf == "something.pdf") { // require a URL
          //  window.location.href = "http://google.com"; 
            alert("start redirect");
        }
    });
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fMeTj/5/

Comment: Except your doing this on a form with with change.

Comment: Ive only this tried it out. It seems this version of IE needs the href bit adding to work. Your answer doesny particularly address this though.